# Encryptar/Decryptar strings com Delphi

Tags: delphi, string, criptografia

Para fins de conhecimento, gostaria de criar a minha propria funcao não muito complexa para encryptar e decryptar strings do programa.

Peguei este pedaco de código da internet `s1[1] := Char((Byte(s1[1]) shl 4) or (Byte(s1[1]) shr 4));`.
Ele é usado para decryptar as string, se eu entendi bem o que ele faz é deslocar 4 bit para esquerda ou direita e depois converte o byte para char. Com esse conseito tentei fazer o inverso para encryptar.

Tentei converter cada caracter para ascii/hexa e deslocar 4 bit para a direita/esquerda com `shr` e `shl` mas o resultado nunca era o esperado.

Aguem poderia corrigir ou mostrar como seria o encrypter deste codigo mostrado ?

Comment: Não dá, não tem praticamente nada na pergunta. Mas isso eu não sei se chamaria de criptografia. Tecnicamente até é, mas parece ser simples demais.

Comment: Desculpa minha falta de atencao o codigo real agora...